# do we use definite article before color or not?

Tags: definite-article

Do we use definite article before colors?

> This command gives me all the clickable content in the red color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.

If the available colors are known, then we would say **the red color**.

If specific colors haven't yet been mentioned, or if a great many colors are available, then we would say **red**. You don't need "color".

By the way, we call it *the* definite article.